# Is there any way in MySQL to trigger something on all of the affected rows at once?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have the following three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Color` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

CREATE TABLE `Pet_Owner` (
  `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `pet_color` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_owner_pet_color`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pet_color`)
    REFERENCES `Color` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

CREATE TABLE `Pet` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `owner` BIGINT NULL,
  `color` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_pet_color_idx` (`color` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_pet_owner_idx` (`owner` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_color`
    FOREIGN KEY (`color`)
    REFERENCES `Color` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pet_owner`
    FOREIGN KEY (`owner`)
    REFERENCES `Pet_Owner` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

The `pet_color` column on person is intended as a denormalization of the color of at least one of his pets.  If he has more than one pet of different colors, the color of any pet will do.  If he has no pets, it should be null.  I want to keep the column in sync with a trigger or some trigger-like mechanism.

Say I have an query that updates the color of 10000 Pets and I want to have a trigger on the `Pet` table that updates the `pet_color` column on the `Pet_Owner` table.  I would rather not loop through each affected row and update rows in the `Pet_Owner` table one at time.

An analogy would be to doing a select on the `Pet` table into a cursor and then looping through the cursor to do the update vs. just using the WHERE clause of an update to achieve the same thing.

So I guess it's a two part question:

1. Are the performance characteristics such that it doesn't really make any difference? It seems like it would but the fact that a WHERE clause is simpler to write than looping through a cursor doesn't necessarily mean that they don't basically make the CPU and disk to about the same thing.
2. If it would make a difference, is there any mechanism, either in the trigger syntax or something else, that would let me act on all the changed rows at once?  I would also accept something that executes outside the context of the original transaction.

Comment: You haven't given any information on what your trigger does, so your question is unanswerable. Edit it to include more details, perhaps with the important parts if the trigger and the table schema and relevant indexes.

Comment: Second part should be covered by the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25318560/trigger-on-mysql-table-when-multiple-rows-deleted/ and I think this will answer part 1 too.